# CSS issues in aligning 3 dynamic div

Tags: html, css

I would be in need of 3 dynamic div containers.

1. dynamic body container
2. dynamic image container
3. dynamic sidebar container

The problem that am facing is that the text should go below the dynamic image container but the dynamic image container is wider then the dynamic sidebar container. The [image](http://creativescripters.com/samples/css-problem.jpg)  better explains my problem.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem- that the text is going below the image container or that it is not? Post your code here so that it will help people to take a crack...

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/Pvjsr/.
I have the div with the following info on the js fiddle.  <div id="ssholder">This is sidebar text that should come under the Gray box BUT THE WIDTH SHOULD BE HALF THE GRAY BOX</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simple you need to know that you just need to `clear:right` to make space for the content on right
here is the fiddle that shows exact result as of your image
http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/3h8Pj/